# PyCharm - how to work in console without opening a project

Tags: python, pycharm, console

I'm new to PyCharm. I'd like to open PyCharm and write code in the console without having to open a project just as I do in IDLE. Is this possible?
Thank you

Comment: Did you try to google "pycharm console"?

Comment: No, it is not possible. You can create an empty scratch project and use it just for the console though.